# Trouble with creating Mandelbrot Set plot in C

Tags: c, struct, printf, fractals, mandelbrot

I am trying to create a Mandelbrot set in C code; my output will be a data file, one column of the real parts and one column of the imaginary parts to be plotted in the Argand or complex plane. I have all the complex math stuff defined in a header `complex.h`and am using a structure `complex` with a `double R` for the real part and `double I` for the imaginary. I am trying to loop trough values for dz and update z iter=80 number of times, or until the point lies outside a defined radius. dz is imaginary, essentially on a range [(dzrmin + i*dzimin), (dzrmax +i*dzimax)]. z is the current complex number, updated as z^2 = dz + z. I have a function `csum()` to sum two complex numbers and a function `csquare()` to properly square a complex number. Here is my whole code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "complex.h"

    int main(void)
    {
        double dzrmin, dzrmax, dzimin, dzimax, dzr,dzi, r0,i0, maxrad; 
        int i,j,k,iter, Ndr,Ndi; 
        complex z, dz; 
        dzrmin = -2.1; 
        dzrmax = 0.6; 
        dzimin = -1.2; 
        dzimax = 1.2; 
        Ndr = 200 ; 
        Ndi = 180; 
        dzr = (dzrmax - dzrmin)/Ndr; 
        dzi = (dzimax - dzimin)/Ndi; 
        r0 = 0.0; 
        i0 = 0.0;
        z.R = r0; 
        z.I = i0; 
        dz.R = dzrmin; 
        dz.I = dzimin; 
        maxrad = 2.0; 
        iter = 80 ; 
        for(i = 0; i < Ndr; i++ )
        {
                    for(j = 0; j < Ndi; j++ )
                    {

                        for(k = 0; k< iter; k++ )
                        {
                    printf("%.6lf %.6lf\n", z.R, z.I ); 
                    z = csum( csquare( z ), dz ) ; 

                    if( cmag(z) > maxrad) k = iter ; 

                }

                dz.I += dzi ; 
            }
            dz.R += dzr; 
            z.R = r0; 
            z.I = i0; 
        }
        return 0; 
    }
```

and my header file `complex.h`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct complexnumber{ double R; double I ; } complex ;
double cmag( complex z)                                                                                                                                             
{
    return pow( z.R*z.R + z.I*z.I, 0.5 ) ; 
}

complex csquare( complex z )             //returns square of a complex
{
    complex product ; 
    product.R = z.R*z.R - z.I*z.I ; 
    product.I = 2*z.R*z.I ; 
    return product ; 

}

complex csum( complex z1, complex z2) // sums two complex numbers 
{
    complex sum ; 
    sum.R = z1.R + z2.R ; 
    sum.I = z1.I + z2.I; 
    return sum ; 
}
```

I am getting a few real values, they get very big really quickly and lie outside a radius of 2, followed by a lot of real parts `-nan` and imaginary parts `-nan`. 
Any suggestions as to what I am missing?

Comment: Be cautious about using `"complex.h"`.  The C99 standard provides a standard header `<complex.h>`, which could easily lead to confusion.  It also provides built-in support for complex types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what results you're expecting, but maybe this instrumented output will help you diagnose the problem:

```
i = 0
i = 0, j = 0
i = 0, j = 0, k = 0: 0.000000 0.000000
i = 0, j = 1
i = 0, j = 1, k = 0: -2.100000 -1.200000
i = 0, j = 2
i = 0, j = 2, k = 0: 0.870000 3.853333
i = 0, j = 3
i = 0, j = 3, k = 0: -16.191278 5.531467
i = 0, j = 4
i = 0, j = 4, k = 0: 229.460353 -180.283027
i = 0, j = 5
i = 0, j = 5, k = 0: 20147.983719 -82736.760384
i = 0, j = 6
i = 0, j = 6, k = 0: -6439430272.999375 -3333957803.416253
i = 0, j = 7
i = 0, j = 7, k = 0: 30350987605860679680.000000 42937577616442236928.000000
i = 0, j = 8
i = 0, j = 8, k = 0: -922453122916892839668491877362832506880.000000 2606395772124638489891541615388582215680.000000
i = 0, j = 9
i = 0, j = 9, k = 0: -5942379156970062175257857153425511563624711669037998408592102022831643293646848.000000 -4808555839107517668369914051798230293111512606121703008400866410836391727464448.000000
i = 0, j = 10
i = 0, j = 10, k = 0: 12189660787377226979177299907109395027773453611835899247334853368367297050334425366457359535808690377953524893091770076537471791519164311649924318416907272192.000000 57148523986878398200502132726020983696472380197135570914789139569106551459309671849901109020634047615447493780748138450365838320365732961897986301575347306496.000000
i = 0, j = 10, k = 1: nan inf
i = 0, j = 10, k = 2: nan nan
```

Note how the inner loop is breaking on the first iteration, all the time.  I think the trouble is that `dz` is set to *-2.1 - 1.2i* to start with.  But without a definition of the Mandelbrot curve you're seeking to plot, I can't tell what should be going on.

This was produced by this single-file variant of your code, using `Complex` in place of the type `complex` which conflicts with the C99 standard.  The complex functions are static because that shuts up the compiler warnings when I compile with:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes cx.c -o cx
```

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct Complex{ double R; double I; } Complex;

static double cmag(Complex z)
{
    return pow(z.R*z.R + z.I*z.I, 0.5);
}

static Complex csquare(Complex z)             //returns square of a complex
{
    Complex product;
    product.R = z.R*z.R - z.I*z.I;
    product.I = 2*z.R*z.I;
    return product;
}

static Complex csum(Complex z1, Complex z2) // sums two complex numbers
{
    Complex sum;
    sum.R = z1.R + z2.R;
    sum.I = z1.I + z2.I;
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    double dzrmin, dzrmax, dzimin, dzimax, dzr, dzi, r0, i0, maxrad;
    int i, j, k, iter, Ndr, Ndi;
    Complex z, dz;
    dzrmin = -2.1;
    dzrmax = 0.6;
    dzimin = -1.2;
    dzimax = 1.2;
    Ndr = 200;
    Ndi = 180;
    dzr = (dzrmax - dzrmin)/Ndr;
    dzi = (dzimax - dzimin)/Ndi;
    r0 = 0.0;
    i0 = 0.0;
    z.R = r0;
    z.I = i0;
    dz.R = dzrmin;
    dz.I = dzimin;
    maxrad = 2.0;
    iter = 80;
    for (i = 0; i < Ndr; i++)
    {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        for (j = 0; j < Ndi; j++)
        {
            printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
            for (k = 0; k < iter; k++)
            {
                printf("i = %d, j = %d, k = %d: ", i, j, k);
                printf("%.6lf %.6lf\n", z.R, z.I);
                z = csum(csquare(z), dz);
                if (cmag(z) > maxrad)
                    break;
            }
            dz.I += dzi;
        }
        dz.R += dzr;
        z.R = r0;
        z.I = i0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```